# Passing statement lambda as parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, lambda

After following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c) on updating a GUI from another thread I wanted to extend the code slightly so that it worked for something other than property assignment.  Specifically I was trying to find a way to assign some functionality directly to a lambda so that I can define the behavior as needed (I modified the original slightly for WPF):

```
    private delegate void UpdateControlThreadSafeDelegate(Control control, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Action> property);
    public void UpdateControl(Control control, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Action> property)
    {

        // If calling thread is not associated with control dispatcher, call our thread safe property update delegate
        if (!control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            control.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateControlThreadSafeDelegate(UpdateControl), new object[] { control, property });
        }
        else
        {
            Action call = property.Compile();
            call();
        }
    }
```

With usage:

```
UpdateControl(lbFoo, () => lbFoo.Items.Clear()); // where lbFoo is a ListBox control
```

This works fine.  But I'd rather allow do something like:

```
UpdateControl(lbFoo, () => { lbFoo.Items.Clear(); lbFoo.Items.Add("Bar");});
```

This does not work, returning error *CS0834: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree*.  The error is clear, I'm just not certain on how best to proceed.  I could follow my original usage and do what I need in several lines, it's just not as tidy.

I'm guessing there is a better/easier way to do what I want.

Comment: Why are you passing an expression and not just an `Action` directly?

Comment: ... Because I'm having a really slow day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use expressions, and just pass the action, like so:

```
public void UpdateControl(Control control, Action actionToExecute)
```

Then you can use this as written.  The only other change will be your else statement, where you would just call this directly:

```
   else
    {
        actionToExecute();
    }
```